# Facebook Marketing API Adset Filtering

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using the Facebook Marketing API and making a call to get the adsets belonging to an adaccount (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/adsets/). My issue is that for one of my ad accounts, there are to many adsets available and as such the call is either taking long or has to many pages. Is there a way that i can possiblly add on date filtering to the request so that it will filter out all those adsets outside of the specified dates?

This is the request i am making with a dummy act id:

```
act_12345678?fields=account_id,name,currency,business{id},adsets{id,name,campaign{id,name,start_time,stop_time,spend_cap,status,insights.date_preset(lifetime){spend}},start_time,end_time,adset_schedule,billing_event,lifetime_budget,budget_remaining,daily_budget,lifetime_imps,status,configured_status,optimization_goal,is_autobid,insights.date_preset(lifetime).as(lifetime_insights){spend}, insights.time_range({'since':'1990-01-01', 'until':'2018-04-26'}).as(insights_to_date){spend}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that the "filtering" parameter works in this case.

For example, if you want to return all adsets that had a start time greater than 12/31/2017 and less than 01/31/2018, you can try the following. 
Note that I had to first convert the start and end dates to a UNIX timestamp:

act_12345678/adsets?filtering=[{'field':'adset.start_time','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':'1514678400'}, {'field':'adset.start_time','operator':'LESS_THAN','value':'1517356800'}]

You can add the "filtering" parameter to your request URL, and it should then filter both on the dates and the fields you specified.

To convert the dates to UNIX time stamp I used the following link: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: I tried this but looks like my query was incorrect fixed it with your suggestions thanks for the helping out :)

Comment: Where on earth is this even documented?!?! I've looked everywhere on the marketing docs and couldnt find a single thing about filtering!

Comment: Might be a year late but was left wondering where this is presented in the documentation as well - it's here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v6.0